# Prism 4.1 How to loading modules with directory scan andapply them to mvvm pattern for navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, prism, prism-4

In prism 4.1 I want to use module loading and build my project using mvvm.
Now I register the module using directory scanning，but navigation is not possible in the view model

the code for the module

```
[Module(ModuleName = "ModuleA", OnDemand = true)]
public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    private IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }
    private ViewA ViewA;

    public ModuleAModule(IRegionManager RegionManager, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (RegionManager != null)
        {
            this.RegionManager = RegionManager;
        }
        if (container != null)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.container.RegisterType<object, ViewA>(nameof(ViewA));

        IRegion MathRegion = RegionManager.Regions["ContentRegions"];
        MathRegion.Add(this.ViewA, "ViewA");
    }
}
```

Then I start in Bootstrapper

```
 class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
    }
}
```

I wrote it like this in the view model

```
class MainWindowViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
    }

    private void Navigate(string navigatePath)
    {

        if (navigatePath != null)
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", new Uri(navigatePath, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Xaml in MainWindow：

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5">
        <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewA" Margin="5">NavigateCommand A</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegions" Margin="5"/>
</DockPanel>
```

```
    public MainWindow(IRegionManager region)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(region);
    }
```

I can't use the buttons to navigate right now, nothing happens after clicking. Is it because I made a mistake when registering the module? Or is the module not found for other reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to register `ViewA` for navigation, not add it to the region immediately.

That is:

```
container.Register<object, ViewA>( nameof(ViewA) );
```

then, upon `RequestNavigate`, the container will create a new instance and the region manager will put it in the region.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. but my navigation still doesn't work.  I added this code where the module was initialized，Where do I need to reslove when I use？

Comment: Not all all, the region manager resolves the new content automatically when navigating. Has your your module been loaded when you navigate?

Comment: I updated the question,added container code in class ModuleAModule, add your code to method Initialize. I just scanned the module in CreateModuleCatalog, i don't know where should I load the modules, is it in Bootstrapper  or in the View Model?

Comment: You load it, when you need it, if set to `OnDemand` as in your code. Otherwise (`OnDemand=false`, the default), Prism loads it automatically when the application is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I gave up the way of the directory scan registration module and changed to a configuration file to register. Now I can run, although I don't understand the principle. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Configuration file or directory scan doesn't really matter, as long as the module is actually loaded. Try the `DirectoryModuleCatalog`, but remove `OnDemand=true` from the module definition.

Comment: I inject `IModuleManager` in the ViewModel constructor, manually import modules using `ModuleManager.LoadModule("ModuleName")` before navigation. Directory scanning now works, as you said. Thank you very much for your reply.